# Structural equation modelling (using only exogenous variables from the main equation)

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, instrumental-variables, endogeneity

Can I use structural equation modelling even if I do not have instruments? (This will be done through using exogenous variables).

Y(Dependent variable) X+A+B+C+D (Independent variables)

X is endogeneous. So, can I use the following equation:

X(Dependent variable) A+B+C (Independent variable)

Moreover, the errors of both equations will be allowed to correlate when using SEM given the endogeneity.

Due to identification(exclusion restriction), two-stage least square cannot be performed, so I did the above using SEM and got the output. From a statistical viewpoint, have I done the above correctly?

Comment: If your model is not identified, the solution you get from maximum likelihood-based SEM will not be unique. Just because the software gives you estimates, that doesn't mean you can proceed with them as if they are true. I'm not exactly sure what you tried and what results you got, though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would it not be unique if I modeled three things in SEM: 1)  Y affected by X+A+B+C+D  2)  X affected by A+B+C  3) errors of both equations allowed to be correlated (to remove endogeneity)? The third point makes this unique from a simple OLS regression. So, from a statistical viewpoint, can I perform SEM analysis (without instruments as mentioned above) and claim that I have addressed endogeneity issue?

Comment: No, because the model is not identified. The model is not identified if you model the correlation between a predictor and the error of its outcome (without an instrument). The model doesn't know whether the association between X and Y comes through X's effect on Y in your first regression or the modeled covariance between the error of X and the error of Y. If you could do this, the problem of causal inference would be solved, because you could isolate the unique effect of X on Y.